# Tunnels and bridges

Tags: simcity-2013

In the latest patch for SimCity 5, they added the tunnel and road bridge function. By pressing "N" or "M" you can lower or raise a road in your city.

- Does this serve any other puporse besides making a city apear more
  "cool"?
- Or does it actually help the city traffic run more smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no - the bridges and tunnel functional does not have a direct effect on traffic management in your city, however because of how traffic management works, they could have a passive effect in that you can use these tools situationally instead of roads traversing longer distances with multiple junctions.

While the tools themselves have no direct impact other than aesthetics, the way traffic travels when junctions and crossings are involved may result in an indirect effect to traffic from using tunnels and bridges to go through and over the landscape, rather than longer roads to go around the landscape.

Answer (score 1):

The significance is that you can overlap roads without intersecting them. The tools can also be used for rail.

For example, if the regional rail connection is on the west side of the map, but you want your tourism district on the east side, you can build rail bridges over/tunnels under any roads you need to cross.

A couple times I have built a road bridge over the highway connection to allow vehicles to get from one side of the highway to the other without intersecting.